# jquery, ajax content is not clickable

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(".location a").click(function()
        {
            var data="type=loc&data="+jQuery(this).attr('name');
            jQuery.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "<?php echo home_url( '/' );?>wp-content/plugins/manageTeam/ajax.php",
                   data: data,
                   beforeSend: function(  ) {
                        jQuery(".teammemcont").hide();

                      },
                   success: function(msg){
                            jQuery(".teammemcont").html(msg);   
                            jQuery(".teammemcont").show();                                   
                    }
                }); 

        });
```

here the content returned by ajax is loaded into teammemcont container.now if i want to click a class of the loaded content by ajax,then it is not working.that means click event is not working on ajax returned content.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the elements in question do not exist in the DOM at the time the event is bound. You need to bind the event with the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method (if you're using jQuery 1.7+) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (if you're using an older version):

```
//jQuery 1.7+
$(".teammemcont").on("click", ".someClass", function() {
    //Newly added element clicked!
});

//Older versions...
$(".teammemcont").delegate(".someClass", "click", function() {
    //Newly added element clicked!
});
```

Comment: i have changed my code as jQuery(".teammemcont").delegate(".location a", "click", function(){...}); but it is not working...if i put body instead of .teammemcont it workes...here location class is outside of teammemcont class.

Comment: You need to call `delegate` on an ancestor of the element you want to trigger the event. So if `.location` is not somewhere inside `.teammemcont` it won't work. As you've discovered, `body` should work because everything should be a descendant.

Comment: so what is the solution for it?plz view the link http://www.tomlodziak.co.uk/gtssweb/?page_id=16 here middle div element can by changed by ajax(by clicking location,a-z or filter)the middle element will show in a pop up after clicking on it.but it is not works on ajax output

Comment: I thought you had already solved it, by using `body` as the selector?

Comment: when i use body it works...it change the elements..but it is not work when click on the ajax output

Answer (score 0):

The `click()` function only binds the event handler to elements that exist when its run, so any dynamically added content won't be affected. In order to do that, you'll need to use a method to add the event handler to dynamically generated content, namely [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7+) or [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (prior to jQuery 1.7). [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated, and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use event delegation for the appended elements to be taken into account. When  simply using .click(), the elements you load with ajax are not in the DOM yet so nothing is binded to them.

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)):

```
$('.teammemcont').on('click', '.location a', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

Basically, you delegate the handling of the click event on '.location a' elements to a parent that exists in the DOM (you could even go up to the document element).
This way, added '.location a' elements within this container will be taken into account automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Click events only work on elements on the page at the time of binding the event listener.

If you want your click event to work on elements created (e.g. in your case via ajax) AFTER the page has loaded then you need to use one of the many delegate functions.

If you're using 1.7 or above then use `on()` if you're using an earlier version then use `delegate()`.

[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `live` method of jquery to bind events to dynamic element. in your case you should use

```
$("class selector").live('click',function(){
//do stuff
});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated. If you're using jQuery 1.7+ you should use `on`. If you're using an older version you should use `delegate`.